# Select distinct inner join including null parameters

Tags: mysql

I have a table **Category**

It has a column **CategoryName**

> 1. car
> 2. plane
> 3. boat

I have another table called **Brand**

It has a column **RelatedCategory**

> 1. ferrari - *1*
> 2. learjet - *2*
> 3. non-categorized - *null*
> 4. audi - *1*

I want to generate a distinct list of brands (null and non-null RelatedCategory) but use CategoryName for the list.

```
select distinct RelatedCategory from brand inner join category on Brand.RelatedCategory=Category.CategoryID
```

I would like the list to be brand category

> 1. car
> 2. boat
> 3. non-categorized

How can I do this? Get the distinct brand category and also non-categorized brands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use LEFT JOIN, it will give you results from the first table that does not exist in the second:

```
select distinct RelatedCategory from category left join brand on
 Brand.RelatedCategory=Category.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. And use `IFNULL` to use the brand name in place of the nonexistent category name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(IFNULL(c.CategoryName, b.name)) AS RelatedCategory
FROM Brand AS b
LEFT JOIN Category AS c ON b.RelatedCategory = c.categoryID
```

Another option is to use `UNION`

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName
FROM Brand AS b
JOIN Category AS c ON b.RelatedCategory = c.categoryID
WHERE RelatedCategory IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Brand
WHERE RelatedCategory IS NULL
```